# NSURLRequest Null (no encoding problems)

Tags: ios, xml, nsstring, nsurlrequest

The problem:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:theList.artist];
NSLog(@"%@",str);     // Log gives me the correct string...

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request]; 
NSLog(@"%@", request);      //Log returns <NSURLRequest (null)>
```

Then if I try:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://totssants.com/index.html"];
                                       //which is the actual URL I am trying to load
```

Everything goes fine... I can pass the string everywhere else but not to the request... 
Could be that a problem with the XML I am parsing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running with NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theList.artist]];?

Comment: If you move `NSLog(@"%@",str);` down to where you're logging the request, does it still look OK?  Or if you use `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:theList.artist];` instead of the first two lines?

Comment: You don't seem to understand how memory management works. You're leaking str (unless you use ARC, in which case alloc/init is redundant).

Comment: Yep, Ihave tried NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theList.artist]];

Comment: I have moved NSLog down there... still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *str = [theList.artist stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And make sure there is no whitespace at the beginning or end of `theList.artist`. That will mess it up too. Has happened to me more than once.

Comment: Now the request log gives me that: <NSURLRequest %0Ahttp://www.totssants.com/index.html>

Comment: That definitely means that there is a whitespace character at the beginning of theList.artist, in this case a linefeed character (ASCII code 0A). You'll need to strip that off. I'll update my answer with more info.

Comment: I've checked everywhere no spaces found.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just noticed an errant semicolon in my code (@"\n;"). I've updated the answer. I just ran some tests and that is most certainly your issue. But it's not a space you're looking for. It's a newline. That's what's causing your issue.